# Page HTML source different from the source I see from "Inspect"

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the savings over on-demand and frequency of interruption information in the table in https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/ with Python.

By clicking 'Inspect' on my web browser (I am using Chrome) and looking through the source, I found that all the data in the table is stored between < tbody > and < /tbody > tags.

However, in my code, when I do

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/instance-advisor/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I see that there is nothing in between < tbody > and < /tbody >.

What is causing this difference and how can I download the full contents of the webpage in Python?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You're not looking through the source, you're looking through the DOM. If you want to view the source, right click and select View Page Source (instead of Inspect). The DOM is constructed by JavaScript which Beautiful Soup doesn't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are loading that data via Ajax after the empty tbody section of the DOM loads.

What you see in the inspector is the rendered page in RAM as it exists in that moment.

The data itself is loaded from here:
https://spot-bid-advisor.s3.amazonaws.com/spot-advisor-data.json

Maybe that is a safer source anyway, as JSON data is easily parsed, and HTML scrapes are easily broken.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How were you able to find the source for the data?

Comment: In Chrome, once you have the developer sidebar open, switch from Elements tab to Network. Then I filtered on XHR (Ajax type requests) and started reading the filenames.


I can't figure out how to get inline images in comments (maybe image markdown only works in posts and answers?) but here's a link to a screengrab of the part of the inspector I am talking about: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DxoU6F_WoAAKkib.jpg:large

Comment: @webdevtool I have the same problem, but in a different wsite, but in this case there's no .json file to read, as is a similar question, I'm asking here how to solve it. Here's the url https://www.fundsexplorer.com.br/ranking can u help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the source of a page and the effective rendered elements. The default view of the 'inspect' window of Chrome shows you the structure of the page the way it is **at that moment**, after any dom manipulation done by javascripts.

If you click at the 'sources' tab you will see that the source matches what python is downloading.
[image]

The data you are looking for is coming from somewhere else (as user webdevtool suggested). Pulling the json data from there ( https://spot-bid-advisor.s3.amazonaws.com/spot-advisor-data.json ) would probably be more reliable and easier to process.

Answer (score 0):

that is probably because of some client-side javascript rendering that the BeautifulSoup doesn't execute so the table remains empty.

But I looked up the Network tab in the Chrome Developer Tools and found the data your are trying to scrape. 
you can download directly the json file from here

https://spot-bid-advisor.s3.amazonaws.com/spot-advisor-data.json